# Farm contracts for pancakeswap

Tags: contract, bep20

I try to fork pancake swap and my question is Do I need to change the contracts for farming or I can use what's in pancakeswap repositories?

{
pid: 108,
lpSymbol: 'ZIL-BNB LP',
lpAddresses: {
97: '',
56: '0xc746337b5f800a0e19ed4eb3bda03ff1401b8167',
},
token: tokens.zil,
quoteToken: tokens.wbnb,
},
{
pid: 107,
lpSymbol: 'pCWS-BNB LP',
lpAddresses: {
97: '',
56: '0x889e81d25bffba437b2a5d3e0e4fc58a0e2749c5',
},
token: tokens.pcws,
quoteToken: tokens.wbnb,
},

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a problem with that part of the code, but I can tell you this:

You need to change those settings as they are related to PCS lpToken, which is created by their Factory contract. After you deploy the Factory and Router, create pairs via interacting with the contract or your frontend (given everything is setup correctly).

That's where I'm having problems, but at least can give you that.